# Node Js Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am working with the mongoose with node.js and I am trying to generate tokens for each user.

here I am not able to understand what is happening for the first return statement and for the second return statement .

Could someone help me with the control flow.

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function(){
 var user = this;
 var access = 'auth';
 var token =jwt.sign({ _id : user._id.toHexString(),access},'123abc');
 user.tokens.push({access,token});
  return user.save().then(()=>{
       return token;
    })
};
```

Comment: See [this](https://davidwalsh.name/promises) for some background.

Comment: The first `return` returns the value created by the `user.save().then(…)` call. If you look into the documentation of `then`, you'll understand what that is

Answer (score 0):

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function(){ // ES5 classic function
 var user = this; // you keep the context in a var
 var access = 'auth'; 
 var token = jwt.sign({ _id : user._id.toHexString(),access},'123abc'); // you call jwt.sign() function
 user.tokens.push({access,token}); // you push some data in user.tokens array
  return user.save().then( () => { // Promise then ES6 arrow function equivalent to function(){ /* do something */ };
       return token; // you return token to your promise
    }); // you return token through user.save()
};
```

More :

Promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

ES6 Arrow function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Hope it ll be clear.

Answer (score 0):

user.save is an asynchronous call. the first return statement returns a promise that tells the caller that the result is not yet known. the second return is the actual value that you are returning through the promise. you might want to explore about promises a bit.

Answer (score 0):

user.save() saves the user to the database which returns a promise which if successful  returns a token.

And BTW update the push to this:
user.tokens = user.tokens.concat([{ access, token }]);

more compatibility with different versions on MongoDB